De-serialize array from RestClient response
I'm able to de-serialize response for "get one" endpoint to desired object type:
        import org.springframework.web.client.RestClient;
        ...
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.create();
        return restClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .header("Authorization", token)
            .retrieve()
            .body(CustomType.class);

However "get all" endpoint returns an array. I'm able to de-serialize response like this:
        import org.springframework.web.client.RestClient;
        ...
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.create();
        return restClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .header("Authorization", token)
            .retrieve()
            .body(ArrayList.class);

This snippet returns an ArrayList of LinkedHashMaps, but is it possible to return ArrayList or array of CustomType objects?

you can use a ParameterizedTypeReference to properly deserialize the JSON array into your custom objects.

    RestClient restClient = RestClient.create();
return restClient.get()
    .uri(url)
    .header("Authorization", token)
    .retrieve()
    .body(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ArrayList<CustomType>>() {});



You can extract it as a List using ParameterizedTypeReference as follows:
RestClient restClient = RestClient.create();
        return restClient.get()
            .uri(url)
            .header("Authorization", token)
            .retrieve()
            .body(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CustomType>>() {});

